# I need to create admin page using React and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, admin, react-admin

I have mongoDB installed on amazon server and front-end, written on React.js. I need to create Admin page using 'react-admin' but I don't know how to make it with my mongoDB because they do not provide dataProvider function that 'react-admin' uses to work https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html .

I tried to write my own dataProvider to route and manage my queries and responses, but because of lack of experience I failed.

```
import { stringify } from 'query-string';
import {
    fetchUtils,
    GET_LIST,
    GET_ONE,
    GET_MANY,
    GET_MANY_REFERENCE,
    CREATE,
    UPDATE,
    UPDATE_MANY,
    DELETE,
    DELETE_MANY,
} from 'react-admin';

/**
 * Maps react-admin queries to a json-server powered REST API
 *
 * @see https://github.com/typicode/json-server
 * @example
 * GET_LIST     => GET http://my.api.url/posts?_sort=title&_order=ASC&_start=0&_end=24
 * GET_ONE      => GET http://my.api.url/posts/123
 * GET_MANY     => GET http://my.api.url/posts/123, GET http://my.api.url/posts/456, GET http://my.api.url/posts/789
 * UPDATE       => PUT http://my.api.url/posts/123
 * CREATE       => POST http://my.api.url/posts/123
 * DELETE       => DELETE http://my.api.url/posts/123
 */

export default (apiUrl, httpClient = fetchUtils.fetchJson) => {

/**
 * @param {String} type One of the constants appearing at the top if this file, e.g. 'UPDATE'
 * @param {String} resource Name of the resource to fetch, e.g. 'posts'
 * @param {Object} params The data request params, depending on the type
 * @returns {Object} { url, options } The HTTP request parameters
 */
const convertDataRequestToHTTP = (type, resource, params) => {

    let url = '';
    const options = {};
    switch (type) {
        case GET_LIST: {
            const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
            const { field, order } = params.sort;
            const query = {
                ...fetchUtils.flattenObject(params.filter),
                _sort: field,
                _order: order,
                _start: (page - 1) * perPage,
                _end: page * perPage,
            };
            url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
            break;
        }
        case GET_ONE:
            url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
            break;
        case GET_MANY_REFERENCE: {
            const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
            const { field, order } = params.sort;
            const query = {
                ...fetchUtils.flattenObject(params.filter),
                [params.target]: params.id,
                _sort: field,
                _order: order,
                _start: (page - 1) * perPage,
                _end: page * perPage,
            };
            url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
            break;
        }
        case UPDATE:
            url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
            options.method = 'PUT';
            options.body = JSON.stringify(params.data);
            break;
        case CREATE:
            url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}`;
            options.method = 'POST';
            options.body = JSON.stringify(params.data);
            break;
        case DELETE:
            url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
            options.method = 'DELETE';
            break;
        case GET_MANY: {
            const query = {
                [`id_like`]: params.ids.join('|'),
            };
            url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
            break;
        }
        default:
            throw new Error(`Unsupported fetch action type ${type}`);
    }
    console.log(url);
    return { url, options };
};

/**
 * @param {Object} response HTTP response from fetch()
 * @param {String} type One of the constants appearing at the top if this file, e.g. 'UPDATE'
 * @param {String} resource Name of the resource to fetch, e.g. 'posts'
 * @param {Object} params The data request params, depending on the type
 * @returns {Object} Data response
 */
const convertHTTPResponse = (response, type, resource, params) => {
    const { headers, json } = response;
    switch (type) {
        case GET_LIST:
        case GET_MANY_REFERENCE:
            if (!headers.has('x-total-count')) {
                throw new Error(
                    'The X-Total-Count header is missing in the HTTP Response. The jsonServer Data Provider expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare X-Total-Count in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?'
                );
            }

            return {
                data: json,
                total: parseInt(
                    headers
                        .get('x-total-count')
                        .split('/')
                        .pop(),
                    10
                ),
            };
        case CREATE:
            return { data: { ...params.data, id: json.id } };
        default:
            return { data: json };
    }
};

/**
 * @param {string} type Request type, e.g GET_LIST
 * @param {string} resource Resource name, e.g. "posts"
 * @param {Object} payload Request parameters. Depends on the request type
 * @returns {Promise} the Promise for a data response
 */

return (type, resource, params) => {
    console.log(type, resource, params);
    // json-server doesn't handle filters on UPDATE route, so we fallback to calling UPDATE n times instead
    if (type === UPDATE_MANY) {
        return Promise.all(
            params.ids.map(id =>
                httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${id}`, {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
                })
            )
        ).then(responses => ({
            data: responses.map(response => response.json),
        }));
    }
    // json-server doesn't handle filters on DELETE route, so we fallback to calling DELETE n times instead
    if (type === DELETE_MANY) {
        return Promise.all(
            params.ids.map(id =>
                httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${id}`, {
                    method: 'DELETE',
                })
            )
        ).then(responses => ({
            data: responses.map(response => response.json),
        }));
    }
    const { url, options } = convertDataRequestToHTTP(
        type,
        resource,
        params
    );

    httpClient(url, options).then(response =>
        convertHTTPResponse(response, type, resource, params)
    );
};
```

};

This function does :

- GET_LIST     => GET http://my.api.url/posts?_sort=title&_order=ASC&_start=0&_end=24
- GET_ONE      => GET http://my.api.url/posts/123
- GET_MANY     => GET http://my.api.url/posts/123, GET http://my.api.url/posts/456, GET http://my.api.url/posts/789
- UPDATE       => PUT http://my.api.url/posts/123
- CREATE       => POST http://my.api.url/posts/123
- DELETE       => DELETE http://my.api.url/posts/123
  */

But I need :

- GET_LIST     => GET https://r8p7az51jd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/viewpoint?$filter={}&$limit={}&$skip={}&$sort={}
- GET_ONE      => GET https://r8p7az51jd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/viewpoint?$filter={_id: '1'}
- UPDATE       => PUT https://r8p7az51jd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/viewpoint?$filter={_id: '1'}
- CREATE       => POST https://r8p7az51jd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/viewpoint?$filter={_id: '1'}
- DELETE       => DELETE https://r8p7az51jd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/viewpoint?$filter={_id: '1'}
  */

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write your own dataProvider.js file that supports your API server, Just keep all the function names and the return data and data type same, React admin has already described this in their documentation. please refer: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html end of this page you will see it